# How can I increase the size of an array by adding a new element to it in the end of the array?

Tags: arrays, c, function

How to increase the size of an array by 1 and add an element to it .I find a difficulty in how to increase the size of an array and at the same time I add a new element to that empty slot of the array … in many functions like searching functions I need this to either check if the element already exist and increment it or add it to the end of the array

here an image for the example...i just want to know what to write if i need my element to be in the end of the array and increase the size of the array

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYL5K.png

Comment: You cannot increase the size of an array. Are you talking about dynamic memory allocations? Please [edit] and show some code

Comment: C arrays are static, so if you want to change their size you need to dynamically allocate them using `malloc` and then use [`realloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)

Comment: Sometimes a linked list is an approach that will work for an indeterminate number of items. Please show more context.

Comment: **Don't post pictures of code**. Post code as properly formatted text.

Comment: i am new to stack overflow and i dont know how to use the site properly ....i just wanted a simple solution how to make the size of the array bigger by adding a new element

Comment: Please take a look at the formatting options for post https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to properly embed code.

Comment: You don't show how you call `adding`, but if you call it with a simple C array, the answer is : no, you cannot increase the size of an array. The answer below gives some hints. You probably need to learn about dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 2):

C arrays are fixed size, which means that you cannot increase it's size.
To help you solve your problem, you need to know in which case you are:

1. Your array is allocated on stack. In this case you can never increase the capacity of your array. You can have a "size", which is a variable that defines how many elements of the array you consider valid. In which case you can do something like

```
int size;
int arr[capacity];
arr[size] = new_element;
size += 1;
```

2. Your array is allocated on the heap. In which case you can resize it by calling [realloc()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

```
int capacity;
int *arr;
arr = realloc(arr, capacity + 1);
capacity += 1;
```